# Any way to minimize a specific window using c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window

I want to minimize a specific window, say Discord for example. Would this be achievable easily, or would it be a large hassle? I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858958/sendmessage-to-3-different-processes-in-c

Answer (score 6):

If you have the window handle, such as from `FindWindow()`, you can use `PostMessage` to send it a [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) message with an `wParam` of `SC_MINIMIZE`.

Comment: Or, use [`ShowWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) with `SW_MINIMIZE`

Comment: Note that this is a request, and the target can choose to ignore it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau does that work if the window belongs to another application?  If it does, you should make a separate answer.

Comment: @IInspectable yes it could ignore it, but if it does the minimize button in the upper-right corner won't work either.